# VSCode textmate scopes not overriding color theme when there are multiple scopes

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, themes

I have installed a custom color theme extension for VSCode and i've been able to override some of the colors from my `settings.json`, however whenever the theme uses more than one scope, overriding doesn't work on those.

**Is there a way to override this color ?**

[image]

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Firefox Devtools Italic]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                { // This works:
                    "scope": ["keyword.control"],
                    "settings": {"foreground": "#FF97E9"}
                },
                { // This doesn't work:
                  "scope": [
                        "meta.function-call.js",
                        "entity.name.function.js"
                    ],
                    "settings": {"foreground": "#B98EFF"}
                },
                { // This doesn't work either:
                    "scope": "meta.function-call.js,entity.name.function.js",
                    "settings": {"foreground": "#B98EFF"}
                },
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the extension you use to see textmate scopes?

Comment: @CemKalyoncu Built-in VSCode: ``CTRL + MAJ + P`` -> type "scope" -> select "Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that we have to **include the space** in the array string for it to work as per the following code:

```json
{
    "scope": ["meta.function-call.js entity.name.function.js"],
    "settings": {"foreground": "#B98EFF"}
},
```

Comment: Hey @Monstar did this work for you? A bunch of my textMateRules broke all of a sudden. When inspecting, it indicates the correct hex code but is rendering a totally different color. Tried above approach and it didn't work on my end, any ideas about this?

Comment: @coreycosman Yeah it does work for me, what your describing seems odd, my styling never actually _broke_ personally.